# windows phone 7 Download files and save it in phone storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

am developing an application which can fetch files from internet.. how do i download and save a "docx" or "wav" file from internet within the application and use it later with other application likes office or windows media player.

Answer (score 1):

You can [download files in the background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202955%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) (ie. they will continue even when your application is not running).

Having said that, you should research the types of files you need to support. For example, you can [play an audio file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) (if the [format is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907934.aspx)) or [add it to Music hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) but you cannot open a file in Office. Very few filetypes can be integrated with, so do some research before you start writing your app otherwise you might be disappointed.

Answer (score -2):

place an image control in your page. here im1 is controls name.
it is working for me

```
string imgurl="http://.........";(path)
Uri addrs=new Uri(imgurl,UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(addrs);
im1.Source = bitmap;
```